# UnitOfWork Nhibernate where should unitofwork live

Tags: nhibernate, unit-of-work

I have read a mixture of reviews about unit of work and nhibernate with the repository pattery. It seems the consensus that the below is incorrect when used in a repository class.

```
public void UpdateCommit(T entity)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
         Session.Update(entity);
         transaction.Commit();
    }
 }
```

My understanding is the the repository should just contain

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    Session.Update(entity);
}
```

I then have another class for my unit of work.

Is it correct in my controller to inject unit of work and then run the below code:

```
_unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();
_portfolioRepository.Create(Mapper.Map<Portfolio>(model));
_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

In effect my web app and where i save the data has a portfoliorepository and a unitofwork concreate class injected and used rather than using

```
 _portfolioRepository.UpdateCommit(entity).
```

In other words should the repository have anything to do with unitofwork or committing transaction. Or should this be handled in the controller or as part of the app life cycle or an interception process.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle

I am looking for best practice nhibernate and unitofwork

Answer (score 0):

In a web application, your unit of work is the request.  So what I do is open a session on beginrequest.  I also have a Transaction ActionFilter that commits/rollsback at the end of the request.  I do think I'm going to refactor this per Mark Seeman's Passive attributes and separate the attribute from the filter.

Your unit of work is now isolated from your repository which is supposed to be an abstraction on a list of items.  The repository has a transact method  that spins up a transaction if there isn't current one for the session.

Here's the begin/end request

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest() { CurrentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession(); }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (CurrentSession != null)
            CurrentSession.Dispose();
    }
```

Here's the Attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ITransaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Transaction = MvcApplication.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!Transaction.IsActive) return;

        if (filterContext.Exception == null)
        {
            Transaction.Commit();
            return;
        }

        Transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

And a generic Repository

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    #region constructor

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Transact

    protected virtual TResult Transact<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        if (_session.Transaction.IsActive)
            return func.Invoke();

        TResult result;
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            result = func.Invoke();
            tx.Commit();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected virtual void Transact(System.Action action)
    {
        Transact(() =>
        {
            action.Invoke();
            return false;
        });
    }

    #endregion

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public void Save(T item)
    {
        Transact(() => _session.Save(item));
    }

    public Boolean Contains(T item)
    {
        if (item.Id == default(Guid))
            return false;

        return Transact(() => _session.Get<T>(item.Id)) != null;
    }

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Transact(() => _session.Query<T>().Count());
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        Transact(() => _session.Delete(item));
        return true;
    }

    public T Load(Guid id)
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Load<T>(id));
    }

    public T Get(Guid id)
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Get<T>(id));
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Query<T>());
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Transact(() => _session.Query<T>().Take(1000).GetEnumerator());
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Transact(() => GetEnumerator());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: is it extra overhead to open a session on every begin and end request when no database activity may be required?

Comment: NHibernate is smart enough to not open a database connection unless you need it.  Opensession() is meant to be a quick method call.  But there will be some since you are still creating a new object